# configuration has an unknown property 'debug'. These properties are valid

Tags: npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4, npm-scripts

I'm creating an isomorphic React app and currently creating a stack.

When I want to test if everything works well with  `npm run build`, I'm receiving the following mistake :

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration has an unknown property 'debug'. These properties are valid:
   object { amd?, bail?, cache?, context?, dependencies?, devServer?, devtool?, entry?, externals?, loader?, mode?, module?, name?, node?, optimization?, output?, parallelism?, performance?, plugins?, profile?, recordsInputPath?, recordsOutputPath?, recordsPath?, resolve?, resolveLoader?, serve?, stats?, target?, watch?, watchOptions? }
   The 'debug' property was removed in webpack 2.0.0.
   Loaders should be updated to allow passing this option via loader options in module.rules.
   Until loaders are updated one can use the LoaderOptionsPlugin to switch loaders into debug mode:
   plugins: [
     new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
       debug: true
     })
   ]
 - configuration.resolve.extensions[0] should not be empty.
   -> A non-empty string
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-isomorphic-app@1.0.0 build: `set NODE_ENV='production' && webpack -p`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the react-isomorphic-app@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Empeek\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-01-17T15_35_03_122Z-debug.log
```

There is probably some mistakes in webpack config pr package json files, but I don't know what exactly

I've got a "debug" property in my package.json file:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "react-isomorphic-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "set NODE_ENV='production' && webpack -p",
    "webpack-devserver": "webpack-dev-server --debug --hot --devtool eval-source-map --output-pathinfo --watch --colors --inline --content-base public --port 8050 --host 0.0.0.0"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.5",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "less": "^3.9.0",
    "less-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "webpack": "^4.28.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
global.Promise         = require('bluebird');

var webpack            = require('webpack');
var path               = require('path');
var ExtractTextPlugin  = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

var publicPath         = 'http://localhost:8050/public/assets';
var cssName            = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'styles-[hash].css' : 'styles.css';
var jsName             = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'bundle-[hash].js' : 'bundle.js';

var plugins = [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      BROWSER:  JSON.stringify(true),
      NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development')
    }
  }),
  new ExtractTextPlugin(cssName)
];

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  plugins.push(
    new CleanWebpackPlugin([ 'public/assets/' ], {
      root: __dirname,
      verbose: true,
      dry: false
    })
  );
  plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin());
  plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin());
}

module.exports = {
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/client.js'],
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
  resolve: {
    root:               path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
    extensions:         ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  plugins,
  output: {
    path: `${__dirname}/public/assets/`,
    filename: jsName,
    publicPath
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader!postcss-loader')
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader!postcss-loader!less-loader')
      },
      { test: /\.gif$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/gif' },
      { test: /\.jpg$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/jpg' },
      { test: /\.png$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/png' },
      { test: /\.svg/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=26000&mimetype=image/svg+xml' },
      { test: /\.(woff|woff2|ttf|eot)/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=1' },
      { test: /\.jsx?$/, loader: 'babel', exclude: [/node_modules/, /public/] },
      { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' },
    ]
  },
  devtool: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? 'source-map' : null,
  devServer: {
    headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' }
  }
};
```

Can you help me to fix this mistake?

Comment: post config, that is where the problem is

Comment: I've added webpack.config file